# How to tell if there are currently any long running queries executing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

*(Related to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/162164/6311))*

If I want to see if there are currently any long-running queries executing on my database, what's the easiest way of checking?  (I expect the answer will be some query on `master..sysprocesses`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) from Adam Machanic is an excellent tool/sp to see what's currently happening on your server.

The below tutorial from Brent Ozar shows how to periodically log sp_whoisactive to a table for later analysis.

https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/

Answer (score 1):

I use the following query to get information about currently running queries. It has the advantage of not requiring any additional packages or addons:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
```

You would probably be most interested in the [start_time], [total_elapsed_time], and [text] fields.